# Where does ContextMenu get its layout from?

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

I'm following the official android tutorial guide to create a context menu when a listview is long clicked.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml

Everything works out, but my contextmenu has a strange margin and the text color of the header is set to blue, which is a color that I never used in my app before.

I want to know where exactly the context menu is getting the information to set its margins and text color? It's certainly not the default settings of a context menu.

Comment: it gets it from R.layout

Answer (score 0):

I think the layout of the context menu depends upon the android version you are using. If you want to customize the menu you should create a layout in the res->menu and then inflate it yourself.

Like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}
```

you can refer to the same doc for custom context menu.